# Unable to get data from Athena on Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, amazon-athena

I was able to connect to Athena using Tableau. I am able to connect and I can see my databases and the tables in them.

When I drag a table to the workspace and click update, I get an error which I am not able to resolve.

[image]

Comment: Can you verify if this request reached Athena from tableau? You can verify it in Athena query history?

Comment: I actually only see one query in my history - not even the ones I am running from the console.